# Issue in view created programmatically in tableviewcell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, view, uiviewcontroller

I am implementing a `UIViewController` that contains a `TableView` , I am trying to add a view created programmatically in `TableViewCell` , on scrolling the view hides and works strange .
anyone can help me

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   if(cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    }
    UIView *BottomView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height , self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    BottomView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
   [cell addSubview:BottomView];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: check question editing

Comment: r u sure you have `Cell` as cell identifier in IB?

Comment: Yes I added the identifier Cell in IB

Comment: @MhmmdBacker have you checked my answer below? is your Problem Solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bro change your BottomView frame and may be it will visible

```
    UIView *BottomView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10 , self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    BottomView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
   [cell addSubview:BottomView];
```

Because you are setting the height of BottomView as self.view.frame.size.height which will put your view as beyond the frame of your cell so change it and it will work.

Comment: It works thx ,but why when i get the cell height as y origin it has this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
[cell addSubview:BottomView];
```

to

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:BottomView];
```